# Setting up untagged VLAN on GE-24F4GBW

Tags: switch, vlan

I got this old boy of a switch, which has been set up with some vlans.

Everything works great when using tagged VLAN id's, and when using VLAN1 (default).

However, I cannot set the PVID of a port to a specific VLAN (10), and then use that VLAN untagged.

It works perfectly if I plug in my laptop with a VLAN tag set on the NIC. However, I can't do this on my windows server.

Any clues?

Comment: When you sa you cannot set it, do you mean when you try to set it your changes are not saved, or that when you change things your network doesn't work?

Comment: A manual that for a supposedly similar model.  http://www.lantechcom.eu/wbcms/media/pdf/manual/M-LGS-1424C.pdf

Comment: @Zoredache I have spent hours looking at that manual, and cannot find any way to set an untagged VLAN on a port.
The settings are saved, but I cannot communicate on the network on VLAN 10, unless I set a tag on the servers NIC, which I cant do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by going to VLAN Setting -> VLAN Port Setting and also defining the VLAN there on the ports you want dedicated to that VLAN.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I have done that too, but I cannot really remember, and since it drove me crazy, I decided to go for a HP switch instead.